# Pre-specifying a default GNU Stow target-directory

Tags: software-installation, symlink, stow

**TLDR:** Can I pre-define a stow folder other than `/usr/local` with [GNU Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/)?

I do not have admin privileges on the machine I use for work, and I was told that I could use [GNU Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/) to manage my installations. The tool looks great, but everywhere in the documentation I read that [stow uses](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Installing-Packages) `/usr/local` as the installation directory where it builds the symlink farm.

Unfortunately this folder was already populated  by `root`, and I do not have write privileges on anything under `/usr/local`.

There is a flag `-t` that I can use in the command line to specify the target directory, but since I will always be using the same (I want my installations to consistently be under the same target directory), I was wondering if there is a way to use a default path of my choice.

Comment: Did you read the INSTALL file?  [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)  I'd never even heard of GNU Stow before, but I found the various prefix options in less than 5 mins.

Comment: Thanks @depquid, the only thing  I found is the command line flag -`-t` that I can pass to stow to specify the target directory. I am looking for something that is a bit more persistent (perhaps an environment variable). From what I read,  the `STOW_DIR` environment variable specifies the `stow directory`and not the target directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure a default target via the `.stowrc` file; please see [this section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/html_node/Resource-Files.html#Resource-Files).  If there is a compelling reason for needing to also set the default target directory via an environment variable, I can implement that for the next release too.

Comment: It would actually be really nice to be able to use environment variables within the `.stowrc`. For example, I like to put my stow files in my home directory so it looks something like `--dir=/my/home/stow`. It would be nice to share this file between computers using something like `--dir=$HOME/stow`.

Comment: Good idea; feel free to [submit a bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=stow).